# sorting list items by price, alphabet and rating jquery

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable

Im little stuck and wondered if anyone can start me off.

I am trying to apply filter methods to my design, and i would like for the list items to be ordered by price when "sort by Price" link is clicked.  I will then try adapting the same method to do the rest myself. 
The code to extract the prices is as follows:

```
$('.price').each(function(){
var allPrices = $(this).html();
});
```

I have no idea what to do after this, please Help me.

you can find what iv done so far [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7gPg7/9/)

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle with a more complete example? I need to see your HTML.

Comment: @oliakaoil it's already in a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

That can probably give you an idea (it's not a good finished solution)

```
var resorts = $(".resorts").clone();
function sortResorts(){
    resorts.sort(function(x,y){
        if($(x).find(".name").text() > $(y).find(".name").text())
            return 1;
        else if($(x).find(".name").text() < $(y).find(".name").text())
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    });
    $(".resorts-container").empty().append($(resorts));
}
```

and you wrap all your `sections` with `<div class='resorts-container'></div>`

the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dh2Lu/) sorts them alphabetically whenever some button is clicked

Comment: how would i restructure this so that it fits into the code iv already written